# How to clear an activity from the second activity going back to home screen in android?

Tags: java, android

example scenario is:
from login screen - main screen - then when i clicked a hide button the app will go to home screen, and when im going to click the app again the main screen would be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire an intent when you want to display the home screen

```
Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(setIntent);
```

So this will be fired on the pressing of your hide button